# Identityserver 4 in docker compose The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-mvc, microservices, identityserver4

I am trying to configure IdentityServer 4 to work in Docker the identity server container itself is running but I can't connect to it from the clients.

My application consists of:

- API
- Client
- Identityserver4

My docker compose looks like

```
services:
 client:
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}client
  ports:
    - '6001:80'
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: UI/client.UI/Dockerfile
  depends_on:
        - db

identityserver:
 image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityserver
 ports:
  - '5001:443'
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Security/IdentityServer/Dockerfile
 depends_on:
        - db

apiservice:
 image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiservice
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: API/Services/api.Service/Dockerfile
 depends_on:
        - db

db:
  image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
  environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "PaSSw0rd"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_PID: Express
  ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  volumes: 
     - mssql-volume:/var/opt/mssql

 networks:
   default:
      driver: bridge

 volumes:
     mssql-volume:
```

My Identityserver `StartUp` class:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    ....

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
            options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10), // ID server cookie timeout set to 10 hours
                CookieSlidingExpiration = true
            };
            options.IssuerUri = "https://172.20.16.1:5001";
        })
        .AddConfigurationStore(options => // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
        {
            ...
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>// this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
        {
            ...
        })
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
 }
```

My client `StartUp` class:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("cookie")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://172.20.16.1:5001";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "ClientMVC";
            options.ClientSecret = "SuperSecretPassword";

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.ResponseMode = "query";

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            .. some scopes
        });
 }
```

I get the following error

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure:
> RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
>
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(bool async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
>
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
>
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)

I tried to add a certificate using the following commands

```
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\IdentityServer.pfx -p passw0rd!
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

but this adds the certificate to `localhost` which is not valid in this case.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for @Tore for his helpful hint in his answer

I followed the following steps to make the identity server work in docker

1. Change the configuration of `identityserver` to make it work in iis
   without `SSL`.
2. Then change the configuration of the `docker`
   container and `docker compose` by removing any `SSL` related
   coniguratiion.
3. Run the application from the `docker compose` and
   everthing is working perfectly
4. Apply small change to the
   configuration to make sure this will be changed in production to
   include the `SSL` certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use a URL like this: https://172.20.16.1:5001

HTTPS requires a certificate and because of that you need a domain name. When I deploy IdentityServer as a container (Azure Container Registry) , I put the signing-key, data-protection key and HTTPS certificate in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: For now I want to configure it for development. How to solve this?

Comment: As a starting point , try to not use HTTPS in development, get it to work without HTTPS locally first, then try to master it with certificates. For certificates to work, you need to create a cert for a domain that points to your identityserver docker container.

Comment: thnanks, will try this